# CAMBIAR DE NULL A EN BLANCO -SQL-

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un inconveniente con esta consulta…

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, count(A.estado) as PRINCIPALES,
        FECHA_CALL = GETDATE ()
      FROM PACIFICARD_GESTION A, Usuarios B
        WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and A.estado = 'ACEPTA' 
        AND   A.operador = B.login
        group by B.nombre
  ) c1 left JOIN (
    SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, COUNT(A.cedula_adicional_1) AS ADICIONALES
      FROM PACIFICARD_GESTION A, Usuarios B
        WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and 
          (A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%CED%' OR 
          A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%PAS%' OR 
          A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%RUC%') and A.operador = B.login
        group by B.nombre  
  ) c2 ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
  ORDER by c1.ASESOR
```

Sucede que en la segunda consulta me despliega resultados NULL.. no es que esté mal… lo que deseo hacer... es que estos registros NULL… se reemplacen con “en blanco” o a su vez poder reemplazar con la palabra ‘S/A’….  si alguien me puede ayudar con este inconveniente, agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué columnas específicamente quieres reemplazar? Y por favor, pon en la pregunta la etiqueta del manejador de base de datos que estás usando, es importante para indicarte qué función debes aplicar a los datos. Gracias.

Comment: las preguntas que son sobre sql, siempre deben indicar que motor de base de datos usas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [ISNULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (SQL Server)

La función acepta un valor a comprobar como primer parámetro, de ser NULL, devolverá como valor el segundo parámetro. De no ser NULL, devolverá el valor suministrado como primer parámetro.

```
ISNULL(valor, 'En blanco')
```

En tu ejemplo, viendo que haces uso de `LEFT JOIN`, creo que esto es lo que buscas:

```
SELECT c1.ASESOR as ASESOR, PRINCIPALES, ISNULL(ADICIONALES, 'En blanco') AS ADICIONALES FROM (
    SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, count(A.estado) as PRINCIPALES,
        FECHA_CALL = GETDATE ()
      FROM PACIFICARD_GESTION A, Usuarios B
        WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and A.estado = 'ACEPTA' 
        AND   A.operador = B.login
        group by B.nombre
  ) c1 left JOIN (
    SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, COUNT(A.cedula_adicional_1) AS ADICIONALES
      FROM PACIFICARD_GESTION A, Usuarios B
        WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and 
          (A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%CED%' OR 
          A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%PAS%' OR 
          A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%RUC%') and A.operador = B.login
        group by B.nombre  
  ) c2 ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
  ORDER by c1.ASESOR
```

Aquí tienes los diferentes nombres de la misma función para otros manejadores SQL: [funciones ISNULL para diferentes tipos de manejadores SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).

Comment: Hola Francisco, gracias por tu ayuda... mira me sale esta respuesta del SQL Mens. 195, Nivel 15, Estado 10, Línea 1
'IFNULL' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido.
Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 8
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'c1'.
Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 16
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'c2'.

Comment: ¿Que servidor SQL usas? Te deje un enlace con los nombres de las funciones dependiendo de tu servidor. Este puede ser `IFNULL`, `ISNULL`, `IsNull`, `NVL`

Comment: Francisco, antes de una respuesta era preciso que el OP especifique el manejador de base de datos que está usando. Fue lo que le pregunté en comentario a su pregunta, precisamente para evitar este tipo de situaciones de responder con un código de un manejador que no es el suyo y que todo termine en un error del tipo *`función no definida`*

Comment: OK... mil disculpas por no especificar... utilizo SQL Server 2012

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes toda la razon, tenia que haberme asegurado primero de que manejador utilizaba, perdón.

Comment: Ahí tienes el dato Fracisco, es `SQL Server 2012`. Propongo que adaptes la respuesta para ese manejador, es prácticamente una letra de diferencia :)

Comment: @luagus77 Ya tienes editada la respuesta con la solución para SQL server.

Comment: Francisco, propongo que mejores la respuesta, la mención que haces en ella a `MySQL` no tiene ningún sentido ni utilidad aquí, sino que más bien confunde. Propongo que indiques la función que se debe usar (poniendo si es posible un enlace a la misma) y explicando brevemente cómo se usa. Ten en cuenta que alguien más puede llegar a esta pregunta buscando ayuda y mientras más clara sea tu respuesta más ayudará y será valorada. Perdona mi insistencia.

Comment: Francisco Garrido y A. Cedano, gracias por sus aportes me ayudaron a solucionar mi inconveniente... y finalmente quedó así la respuesta.  SELECT c1.ASESOR as ASESOR, PRINCIPALES, ISNULL(ADICIONALES, '') AS ADICIONALES, FECHA_CALL = GETDATE () FROM (........

Comment: @A.Cedano Al contrario, muchas gracias por ayudarme a mejorar la respuesta. Tendre estas cosas en cuenta para futuras respuesta.

Comment: @luagus77 considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha resuelto el problema. Lo puedes hacer activando la marca de cotejo gris que está a la izquierda. De paso la puedes votar positivamente si no lo has hecho ya. Saludos.